# add customize field in openerp 7, but no result

Tags: python, django, odoo, openerp-7

I'm trying to customize customer form in my openerp by adding 1 field (ex. Hobby field), I've already make `__init__.py`, `__openerp__.py`, `customer_inher.py`, `customer_inher_view.xml`, but nothing changed. I use **Openerp 7** and **Windows 7**, please check my code below and please tell me what should i do, Really need your help guys..

**_*init*_.py**

```
import partner_ai
```

**_*openerp*_.py**

```
{
    'name': 'Base',
    'version': '1.3',
    'category': 'partner',
    'author': 'OpenERP SA',
    'maintainer': 'OpenERP SA',
    'website': 'http://www.openerp.com',
    'depends': [base],
    'data': [
        'partner_view.xml',
    ],
    'demo': [],
    'test': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,
    ],
}
# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

**partner_ai.py**

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {'hobby' : fields.char('Hobby Pribadi', size=20, help='bujang, lajang, etc')}

   def format_npwp(self, cr, uid, ids, hobby):
        if status:

            result = ''
            warning = {"title": ("Hobby Partner salah!"), "message": ("Hobby salah, jangan ada selain karakter")}

            elif status.isdigit():
                return {'warning': warning, 'value': {'hobby': result}}

            else:
                result = status
                return {'value': {'hobby': result}}
        return True

partner()
```

**partner_ai_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="partner_ai_view">
            <field name="name">partner.ai</field>            
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>            
            <field name="type">form</field>                         
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="email" position="after">
                    <field name="hobby"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

I place above files in /addons/partner_ai/..

Answer (score 1):

in your **openerp**.py file u are caliing the original 'partner_view.xml'
It shud be :

```
'data': [
    'partner_ai_view.xml',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting->technical->database structure->fields there u create your new custom field and add it using edit form view by activating developers mode